# 1000 DOM elements on a single page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-canvas

For a project of big "text map" [BigPicture](https://github.com/josephernest/bigpicture.js/), I need to have more than 1000 text inputs.
**When you click + drag, you can "pan" the displayed area.**

But the performance is very poor (both on Firefox and Chrome) : rendering 1000+ DOM elements is not fast at all.

*Of course, another solution with better performance would be : work on a  `<canvas>`, render text as bitmap on it, and each time we want to edit text, let's show a unique DOM `<textarea>`, that disappears what editing is finished, and text is rendered as bitmap again... **It works** (I'm currently working in this direction) but it needs much more code in order to provide editing on a canvas.*

**Question : Is it possible to improve performance for rendering of 1000+ DOM elements on a HTML page, so that I don't need to use `<canvas>` at all ?**

**Or will it be impossible to have good performance when panning a page with 1000+ DOM elements ?**

[image]

---

*Notes :*

1) In the demo here I use `<span contendteditable="true">` because I want multiline input + autoresize, but the rendering performance is the same with standard `<textarea>`.*

2) For reference, this is how I create the 1000 text elements.

```
for (i=0; i < 1000; i++)
{
  var blax = (Math.random()-0.5)*3000;
  var blay = (Math.random()-0.5)*3000;
  var tb = document.createElement('span');
  $(tb).data("x", blax / $(window).width());
  $(tb).data("y", blay / $(window).height());
  $(tb).data("size", 20 * currentzoom);
  tb.contentEditable = true;
  tb.style.fontFamily = 'arial';
  tb.style.fontSize = '20px';
  tb.style.position  = 'absolute';
  tb.style.top = blay + 'px';
  tb.style.left = blax + 'px';
  tb.innerHTML="newtext";
  document.body.appendChild(tb);
}
```

Comment: first of all adding elements one by one causing to many DOM manupulation instead try using string concatenate and update the innerHTML after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution was given by [@Shmiddty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1585400/shmiddty) which is much faster to all previous attempts : all elements should be wrapped, and only the wrapper has to be moved (instead of moving each element) :

http://jsfiddle.net/qhskacsw/

**It runs smooth and fast even with 1000+ DOM elements.**

---

```
var container = document.createElement("div"),
    wrapper = document.createElement("div"),
    dragging = false,
    offset = {x:0, y:0},
    previous = {x: 0, y:0};

container.style.position = "absolute";
wrapper.style.position = "relative";
container.appendChild(wrapper);
document.body.appendChild(container);

for (var i = 1000, span; i--;){
    span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = "banana";
    span.style.position = "absolute";
    span.style.top = (Math.random() * 3000 - 1000 | 0) + 'px';
    span.style.left = (Math.random() * 3000 - 1000 | 0) + 'px';

    wrapper.appendChild(span);
}


// Don't attach events like this. 
// I'm only doing it for this proof of concept.

window.ondragstart = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}

window.onmousedown = function(e){
    dragging = true;
    previous = {x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY};
}

window.onmousemove = function(e){
    if (dragging){
        offset.x += e.pageX - previous.x;
        offset.y += e.pageY - previous.y;
        previous = {x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY};

        container.style.top = offset.y + 'px';
        container.style.left = offset.x + 'px';
    }
}

window.onmouseup = function(){
    dragging = false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For something like this you could make use of document fragment, these are DOM nodes that are not part of the actually DOM tree (more info can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment), so you can do all your setup on the fragment and then append the fragment which will only be causing the one re flow rather than 1000.

So here is an example -http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/awzoz7bj/ - a quick check on run time it takes around 60-70ms to run

```
var currentzoom = 1;
var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var start = new Date();
for (i=0; i < 1000; i++)
{
  var blax = (Math.random()-0.5)*3000;
  var blay = (Math.random()-0.5)*3000;
  var tb = document.createElement('span');
  $(tb).data("x", blax / $(window).width());
  $(tb).data("y", blay / $(window).height());
  $(tb).data("size", 20 * currentzoom);
  tb.contentEditable = true;
  tb.style.fontFamily = 'arial';
  tb.style.fontSize = '20px';
  tb.style.position  = 'absolute';
  tb.style.top = blay + 'px';
  tb.style.left = blax + 'px';
  tb.innerHTML="newtext";
  docFragment.appendChild(tb);
}

document.body.appendChild(docFragment);

var end = new Date();
console.log(end-start)
```

compared to the original which took around 645ms to run http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/896pusex/

**UPDATE** So for improving the dragging speed again keep the individual edits out of the DOM to avoid the cost of the reflow 1000 times every mouse drag

so here is one way using jquery's detach() method (example http://jsfiddle.net/sf72ubdt/). This will remove the elements from the DOM but give them to you with all their properties so you can manipulate them and reinsert them later on

```
redraw = function(resize) {
    //detach spans
    var spans = $("span").detach();
    //now loop other them, because they are no longer attached to the DOM any changes are
    //not going to cause a reflow of the page
    $(spans).each(function(index) {
        var newx = Math.floor(($(this).data("x") - currentx) / currentzoom * $(window).width());
        var newy = Math.floor(($(this).data("y") - currenty) / currentzoom * $(window).height());

        if (resize) {
            displaysize = Math.floor($(this).data("size") / currentzoom);
            if (displaysize) {
                $(this).css({
                    fontSize: displaysize
                });
                $(this).show();
            } else
                $(this).hide();
        }
        //changed this from offset as I was getting a weird dispersing effect around the mouse
        // also can no longer test for visible but i assume you want to move them all anyway.
        $(this).css({
            top: newy + 'px',
            left: newx + 'px'
        });
    });
    //reattach to the body
    $("body").append(spans);

};
```

**UPDATE 2 -**

So to get a little more performance out of this you can cache the window width and height, use a vanilla for loop, use vanilla js to change the css of the span. Now each redraw (on chrome) takes around 30-45 ms (http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/orpupsge/) compared to my above update which saw them at around 80-100ms (http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/b68r2xeu/)

so here is the updated redraw

```
redraw = function (resize) {
    var spans = $("span").detach();
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();

    for (var i = spans.length; i--;) {
        var span = $(spans[i]);
        var newx = Math.floor((span.data("x") - currentx) / currentzoom * width);
        var newy = Math.floor((span.data("y") - currenty) / currentzoom * height);
        if (resize) {
            displaysize = Math.floor(span.data("size") / currentzoom);
            if (displaysize) {
                span.css({
                    fontSize: displaysize
                });
                span.show();
            } else span.hide();
        }


        spans[i].style.top = newy + 'px',
        spans[i].style.left = newx + 'px'
    }

    $("body").append(spans);
};
```

---

SNIPPET EXAMPLE -

```js
var currentzoom = 1;
var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var start = new Date();
var positions = []
var end = new Date();
console.log(end - start);

var currentx = 0.0,
currenty = 0.0,
currentzoom = 1.0,
xold = 0,
yold = 0,
button = false;

for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
var blax = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 3000;
var blay = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 3000;

var tb = document.createElement('span');
$(tb).data("x", blax / $(window).width());
$(tb).data("y", blay / $(window).height());
$(tb).data("size", 20 * currentzoom);
tb.contentEditable = true;
tb.style.fontFamily = 'arial';
tb.style.fontSize = '20px';
tb.style.position = 'absolute';
tb.style.top = blay + 'px';
tb.style.left = blax + 'px';
tb.innerHTML = "newtext";
docFragment.appendChild(tb);
}
document.body.appendChild(docFragment);

document.body.onclick = function (e) {
if (e.target.nodeName == 'SPAN') {
    return;
}
var tb = document.createElement('span');

$(tb).data("x", currentx + e.clientX / $(window).width() * currentzoom);
$(tb).data("y", currenty + e.clientY / $(window).height() * currentzoom);
$(tb).data("size", 20 * currentzoom);
tb.contentEditable = true;
tb.style.fontFamily = 'arial';
tb.style.fontSize = '20px';
tb.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
tb.style.position = 'absolute';
tb.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
tb.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
document.body.appendChild(tb);
tb.focus();
};

document.body.onmousedown = function (e) {
button = true;
xold = e.clientX;
yold = e.clientY;
};

document.body.onmouseup = function (e) {
button = false;
};

redraw = function (resize) {
var start = new Date();
var spans = $("span").detach();
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();

for (var i = spans.length; i--;) {
    var span = $(spans[i]);
    var newx = Math.floor((span.data("x") - currentx) / currentzoom * width);
    var newy = Math.floor((span.data("y") - currenty) / currentzoom * height);
    if (resize) {
        displaysize = Math.floor(span.data("size") / currentzoom);
        if (displaysize) {
            span.css({
                fontSize: displaysize
            });
            span.show();
        } else span.hide();
    }


    spans[i].style.top = newy + 'px',
    spans[i].style.left = newx + 'px'
}

$("body").append(spans);
var end = new Date();
console.log(end - start);
};

document.body.onmousemove = function (e) {
if (button) {
    currentx += (xold - e.clientX) / $(window).width() * currentzoom;
    currenty += (yold - e.clientY) / $(window).height() * currentzoom;

    xold = e.clientX;
    yold = e.clientY;

    redraw(false);
}
};

$(function () {
$('body').on('mousedown', 'span', function (event) {
    if (event.which == 3) {
        $(this).remove()
    }
})
});

zoomcoef = function (coef) {
middlex = currentx + currentzoom / 2
middley = currenty + currentzoom / 2
currentzoom *= coef
currentx = middlex - currentzoom / 2
currenty = middley - currentzoom / 2
redraw(true)
}

window.onkeydown = function (event) {
if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 61) {
    zoomcoef(1 / 1.732);
    event.preventDefault();
}
if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 169) {
    zoomcoef(1.732);
    event.preventDefault();
}
if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 48) {
    zoomonwidget(1 / 1.732);
    event.preventDefault();
}
};
```

```css
  html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer ! Even if it's good to reduce time at the startup for text creation (645 -> 60 ms is really great!),  I'm more interested into performance when panning the page (just do `CLICK+DRAG` mouse on my first demo page). Does your trick work as well to speed up the "panning" ?   I don't see exactly how to use the `docFragment` for panning (ie re-setting each element's x,y position)

Comment: can you show what code you use to do your panning and then I can update my answer if it works

Comment: When mouse button is clicked down, for each mousemove, I use `redraw()` from http://s419743653.onlinehome.fr/things/TextboxesOnClick4%28contenteditable-lotsof1000-simpler%29.html . Basically in this function, there is a loop on all DOM elements, and I change their position : `$(this).offset({ top: newy, left: newx})`

Comment: updated my answer to show how you can improve the drag performance.

Comment: Thanks @Quince for this update, this improves a lot the drag performance... But still, unfortunately, the drag speed is not fast enough (at least on my computer, with Firefox).

What would you do personnally in such a case ? Redo the whole thing with `<canvas>` (I planned to do it), or find some other improvements ?

Comment: More generally, do you think some further optimization is possible ? Caching ? (what kind of ?)

Comment: Not sure I've not used canvas much would you still need to loop over every object once it is on the canvas to adjust it's position?  If so then it will hit the same bottle neck as this example.  In terms of more performance might be able to get a little better as not sure if. Each is the fastest way to loop but this is probably close to its fastest running speed. Oh also Just noticed I used the wrong example in my snippet,  the snippet uses clone where as the fiddle uses detach which is faster.

Comment: Actually reading up on the vanilla looping vs jquery looping and the performance increase is quite large so maybe there is more that improvements that can be made out of this. Also both my snippet and fiddle were using clone, ive update the example fiddle link now to show the detach in action

Comment: Thanks for these updates, now `detach()` are used everywhere, it's the best, am I right ? 
I can imagine that the performance cost is not the looping itself, but more the graphical rendering of the textboxes (font rendering, etc.)

Comment: yeah i changed both snippet and fiddle to use detach(). Yes thats where the biggest gain has been made because now it only does one reflow every time redraw is called. The loop can have an effect but not as big as what detach() has made, im intrested though so going to try one more example with a different loop to see what can be done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61524/discussion-between-quince-and-basj).

Answer (score 1):

**IMHO, I would go with your current thinking to maximize performance.**

Reason: 1000+ DOM elements will always limit performance.

Yes, there is slightly more coding but your performance should be much better.

- create one large offscreen canvas containing all 1000 texts.
- Use `context.textMeasure` to calculate the bounding box of all 1000 texts relative to the image.
- Save the info about each text in an object

  ```
  var texts=[];
  var texts[0]={ text:'text#0',  x:100, y:100, width:35, height:20 }
  ```

  ...
- `context.drawImage` that image on a canvas using an offset-X to 'pan' the image.  This way you only have 1 canvas element instead of 1000 text elements.
- In the mousedown handler, check if the mouse position is inside the bounding box of any text.
- If the mouse is clicked inside a text bounding box, absolutely position an input-type-text directly over the text on the canvas. This way you only need 1 input element which can be reused for any of the 1000 texts.
- Use the abilities of the input element to let the user edit the text.  The canvas element has no native text editing abilities so don't "recreate the wheel" by coding canvas text editing.
- When the user is done editing, recalculate the bounding box of the newly edited text and save it to the text object.
- Redraw the offscreen canvas containing all 1000 texts with the newly edited text and draw it to the onscreen canvas.
- Panning: if the user drags the onscreen canvas, draw the offscreen canvas onto the onscreen canvas with an offset equal to the distance the user has dragged the mouse.  Panning is nearly instantaneous because **drawing the offscreen canvas into the onscreen canvas-viewport is much, much faster than moving 1000 DOM input elements**

**[ Addition: full example with editing and panning ]**

**Best Viewed In Full Screen Mode**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

var texts=[];
var fontSize=12;
var fontFace='arial';

var tcanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var tctx=tcanvas.getContext("2d");
tctx.font=fontSize+'px '+fontFace;
tcanvas.width=3000;
tcanvas.height=3000;

var randomMaxX=tcanvas.width-40;
var randomMaxY=tcanvas.height-20;
var panX=-tcanvas.width/2;
var panY=-tcanvas.height/2;
var isDown=false;
var mx,my;       

var textCount=1000;
for(var i=0;i<textCount;i++){
  var text=(i+1000);
  texts.push({
    text:text,
    x:parseInt(Math.random()*randomMaxX),
    y:parseInt(Math.random()*randomMaxY)+20,
    width:ctx.measureText(text).width,
    height:fontSize+2,
  });
}

var $textbox=$('#textbox');
$textbox.css('left',-200);
$textbox.blur(function(){
  $textbox.css('left',-200);
  var t=texts[$textbox.textsIndex]
  t.text=$(this).val();
  t.width=ctx.measureText(t.text).width;
  textsToImage();    
});


textsToImage();

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});


// create one image from all texts[]
function textsToImage(){
  tctx.clearRect(0,0,tcanvas.width,tcanvas.height);
  for(var i=0;i<textCount;i++){
    var t=texts[i];
    tctx.fillText(t.text,t.x,t.y)
    tctx.strokeRect(t.x,t.y-fontSize,t.width,t.height);
  }
  redraw();
}

function redraw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(tcanvas,panX,panY);
}

function handleMouseDown(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // is the mouse over a text?
  var hit=false;
  var x=mx-panX;
  var y=my-panY;
  for(var i=0;i<texts.length;i++){
    var t=texts[i];
    if(x>=t.x && x<=t.x+t.width && y>=t.y-fontSize && y<=t.y-fontSize+t.height){
      $textbox.textsIndex=i;
      $textbox.css({'width':t.width+5, 'left':t.x+panX, 'top':t.y+panY-fontSize});
      $textbox.val(t.text);
      $textbox.focus();
      hit=true;
      break;
    }
  }

  // mouse is not over any text, so start panning
  if(!hit){isDown=true;}
}

function handleMouseUpOut(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  panX+=mouseX-mx;
  panY+=mouseY-my;
  mx=mouseX;
  my=mouseY;
  redraw();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#wrapper{position:relative; border:1px solid blue; width:600px; height:600px;}
#textbox{position:absolute;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click on #box to edit.<br>Tab to save changes.<br>Drag on non-text.</h4><br>
<div id=wrapper>
  <input type=text id=textbox>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=600></canvas>
</div>
<button></button>
```

Comment: Thanks for these hints! *(This is more or less where my thoughts went, but you also gave me some new ideas which seem great!).* About "create one image of all 1000 texts.", do you mean I should store an image of the text in the text object, for each text ? How would you do this ? This seems very interesting !

Comment: I've edited my answer to maximize performance by using (1) an on-screen canvas used as a viewport: 600px by 600px, (2) and offscreen canvas used to hold every text: 3000px X 3000px, (3) one input-type-text used to edited every text by repositioning this one input over any text the user clicks to edit. The onscreen canvas pans over the offscreen canvas--very fast! Since there is just 1 DOM input-text instead there is almost no lag versus a DOM containing 1000 elements. Let me know what you think and good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

I just run couple tests and it seems that moving absolutely positioned (position:absolute;) DOM elements (divs) with CSS transform:translate is even faster (by about 30%) than doing it via Canvas. But I was using CreateJS framework for the canvas job so my results may not hold for other use cases.